# Garbage printed on mouse move after "set statusline"

Tags: vim

I set the statusline with the following command:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%F\ %r\ [Branch\ %{system(\"echo\ -n\ OK\")}]\ %=[Hex=\%02.2B]\ [Column\ %c]\ [Line\ %l/%L]
hi StatusLine ctermbg=black ctermfg=gray
```

When I scroll mouse wheel, symbols are printed in the window: `^[OA` and `^[OB`, and they can be cleared e.g. by pressing PgUp/-Down.
I found out that `system(...)` part of the statusline causes the behavior, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Note: `Ctrl-L`  removes those characters but not permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct the problem is in `system`.

> When prepended by |:silent| the shell will not be set to
>   cooked mode.  This is meant to be used for commands that do
>   not need the user to type.  It avoids stray characters showing
>   up on the screen which require |CTRL-L| to remove. >
>       `:silent let f = system('ls *.vim')`

So you can avoid this by creating function that calls `system` with `silent`

```
set laststatus=2
function! EchoOk()
  silent let es = system("echo -n OK")
  return es
endfunction
set statusline=%F\ %r\ [Branch\ %{EchoOk()}]\ %=[Hex=\%02.2B]\ [Column\ %c]\ [Line\ %l/%L]
hi StatusLine ctermbg=black ctermfg=gray
```

Comment: Hm... I have tried it and it does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @Student4K Very weird, it works for `7.4.1689`. What version do you use?

Comment: My version is 7.4.52, but I have managed to make it work by saving result of EchoOk in a variable and accessing it in `statusline`.